# Problem with desktop image background (visually)

Tags: release-loki, desktop, nvidia

I just installed loki, but sometimes the background image becomes black or strange. When I change the background image the problem is fixed. however it is annoying

GPU: nvidia queadro k620 (driver from nvidia webpage installed (367.44) )

CPU:  Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-6700 CPU @ 3.40GHz

RAM: 32 GB
[image]

[image]